# how to catch when uilocalnotification is fired (not when it is clicked) in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa, uilocalnotification

I have a local notification. It fires everyday at the same time.

The problem is that the `didReceiveLocalNotification` function is not triggered unless the user clicks it.

I have a process that needs to kick off when the local notification fires (not when it is clicked) because the user may not sometimes click the local notification.

Am I able to access this event? If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: If the app runs you can check the time and realize that it's time to do whatever.  If the app doesn't run you can't do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are unable to access this event if your application is not running in the background. And there is no way to guarentee your application will run in the background at the firing of the `UILocalNotification`.

This is a limitation of iOS programming.

Secondly, It doesn't sound like you need a `UILocalNotification`. The type of interaction you are describing is a daily process. It it doesn't matter that the user clicks it or not, then why would you display a notification to the user that it did at all. Regardless, you cannot create daily processes like these that do not require user interaction. UILocalNotification is the closest thing you will get.

Gonna have to venture into Jailbroken territory to do something like that.